# Scala group by and find min and max from List[String]

Tags: scala

I've following list of values in Scala and want to group by these values in such a way that I can get min and max timestamp of each value for each particular day :-

```
val data = List( (123 , 2018-04-30 10:15:30),
(123 , 2018-04-30 11:15:30),
(123 , 2018-04-30 12:22:30),
(223 , 2018-04-22 10:15:30),
(223 , 2018-04-22 13:15:30))
```

I want output as

```
List((123, 2018-04-30, 2018-04-30 10:15:30 , 2018-04-30 12:22:30),
(223, 2018-04-22, 2018-04-22 10:15:30 , 2018-04-30 13:15:30))
```

Hope this clarifies my query

Thanks,

Comment: @philantrovert - what no attempt ? I didn't understand why this question is off topic. I'm new in some concepts and I believe that Stackoverflow is a platform where users can submit their queries and get response. Please don't give negative vote as it demotivates a user, rather you can help him to understand where they have done mistake so that they can fully utilise this wonderful platform.

Comment: Hi! StackOverflow is essentially a Q&A website. As much as we'd like to help you in providing a solution to your problem, it would be easier for us if you'd first show us what you tried to achieve that. If you click on the link I referred to in my above comment, you'll see why it makes things easier if there's an attempt included in the question. The negative vote is not to demotivate you. And, I have already explained in my comment why I'm downvoting it and what is wrong with the question. I'd also recommend reading [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @philantrovert - Thanks for explaining this. But I made an attempt to do I was getting stuck thats why tried to raise a question over here. anyways, I'm banned from asking question. So no more worries I guess. I was expecting to learn more from this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that you pass in the data in the form of List[String]

```
    val data = List(
  ("123 , 2018-04-30 10:15:30"),
  ("123 , 2018-04-30 11:15:30"),
  ("123 , 2018-04-30 12:22:30"),
  ("223 , 2018-04-22 10:15:30"),
  ("223 , 2018-04-22 13:15:30")
)
```

and that your data has the date always in the form of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, then you can create a function that will receive this list as input and output another list that will contain the data in the desired format.

Your function is as follows

```
def func(data: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  data.map {
    x =>
      (x.split(",")(0), formatter.parse(x.split(",")(1)))
  }.groupBy(_._1).map {
    y =>
      y._1 + " , " + formatter.format(y._2.map(_._2).min) + " , " + formatter.format(y._2.map(_._2).max)
  }.toList
}
```

If you call the function `func(data)` you will get the output in the list form as

`List(223  , 2018-04-22 10:15:30 , 2018-04-22 13:15:30, 123  , 2018-04-30 10:15:30 , 2018-04-30 12:22:30)` .

Hope this solves your query!!!

Comment: Hi, it worked , just had to do little editing as I wanted it to grouped on the basis of date wise , your answer was giving overall min and max values. Overall it helped. Thanks for your precious time and response. Accepted your answer.